# Python, looking to move text from left to right

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

**This code moves the text from left to right using `PyQt4`. My question is, are there other ways to do it?**

```
# -*-coding:utf8 -*-
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QGraphicsView, QPainter, QColor, QWidget,
                         QGraphicsScene, QFont, QLabel, QGraphicsSimpleTextItem,
                         QBrush, QLinearGradient, QPixmap, QGraphicsTextItem, QPushButton,
                         QVBoxLayout, QTextDocument)

from PyQt4.QtCore import (QObject, QPointF, QPropertyAnimation,
                          pyqtProperty, Qt, QAbstractAnimation, QRectF)
import sys

data = [u"I want to make text within an ad bar that moves as there is on the TV screen like this"]


class Text(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Text, self).__init__()

        doc = QTextDocument("%s" % data[0])
        doc.setDefaultStyleSheet(
            "body { color : green; background-color : black }")
        doc.setDefaultFont(QFont("Times", 20, QFont.Bold))

        self.Text_item = QGraphicsTextItem()
        self.Text_item.setDocument(doc)

    def _set_pos(self, pos):

        self.Text_item.setPos(pos)

    pos = pyqtProperty(QPointF, fset=_set_pos)


class Example(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initView()

    def initView(self):

        self.text = Text()

        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.text, b"pos")
        self.anim.setDuration(19000)
        self.anim.setLoopCount(4)
        self.anim.setStartValue(QPointF(-1850.0, 450.0))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QPointF(800.0, 450.0))

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.scene.addItem(self.text.Text_item)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.setWindowTitle("Text moveing")
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.anim.start(QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Example()
    rect = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
    view.resize(int(rect.width() * 0.75), int(rect.height() * 0.9))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```